# How can I init a text field in a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uialertview

The updated `UIAlertView` now has a style which allows a Text input field in `UIAlertView` i.e.

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```

This works well but I wanted to init the input text with a defualt text like "sample".

I see that folks in the past have used undocumented api like (which works great)

```
[alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"sample text" label:@"Text Field"];
```

but since this is still not an official Apple public API I can't use it.

Any other way to handle this? I did try to init in `willPresentAlertView` but text field seem to be read-only.

Thanks

Answer (score 57):

The `UIALertView` has a `textFieldAtIndex:` method that returns the `UITextField` object you want.

For a `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`, the index of the textfield is 0.

You can then set the placeholder (or text) property of the textfield:

```
UIAlertView *alert = ....
UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.placeholder = @"your text";
```

[UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more.  textFieldAtIndex generates this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textFieldIndex (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'.

Comment: worked for me, but how come !!!!
how the effect reflects to the alert !!
can't understand !

Comment: @Symmetric, make sure you set [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput]; before trying to get the UITextField

Answer (score 9):

Easy way to do

```
 UIAlertView *alerView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"your title" message:@"your message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alerView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [[alerView textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"placeholder text..."];
    [alerView show];
```

Answer (score 8):

Not tested, but I assume this would work:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
UITextField* textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.text = @"sample";
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 6):

For setting default value in uiAlertView this thing will work.

```
UIAlertView *alert = ....
UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
[textField setText:@"My default text"];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add New Category"
                                                      message:nil
                                                     delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Add"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [message show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Add"])
    {
        UITextField *username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Category Name: %@", username.text);
    }
}
```